# Why does "indicator-datetime" have broken dependencies, and how can I fix it?

Tags: package-management, indicator

I just upgraded to ubuntu 11.10 from 11.04 and clock/calendar doesn't appear on the bar.
So I figured out that `indicator-datetime` wasn't installed. When I tried to install it
the following error appears:

```
xxx@yyy:/$ sudo apt-get install indicator-datetime
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 indicator-datetime : Depends: libecal1.2-10 (>= 3.2.1) but 3.2.0-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
                      Depends: libedataserver1.2-15 (>= 3.2.1) but 3.2.0-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
                      Depends: libedataserverui-3.0-1 (>= 3.2.1) but 3.2.0-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: what is the complete output of `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` ? (please add this to your question)

Comment: here is the report [link](https://sites.google.com/site/mygithub/sudo-apt-get-update-and-upgrade)

Comment: you've got several PPAs - although the trace doesnt show the details - Try disabling them in Software Sources - rerun the "output" above again and then reinstall indicator-datetime.

Comment: ok, from our advice I figure out where is the problem. the problem was that `Important security updates, Recommended updates and Pre-released updates` where deactivated in Software sources. I activate them, and then run `apt-get update` and then `apt-get install indicator-datetime` and then restart and it works.

Answer (score 1):

This problem occurs when you have updated some packages but (at the time) certain dependencies had not yet been built and available in the repository.

To solve it, refresh your sources (`sudo apt-get update`) and then install the `indicator-datetime` package again.

Comment: `apt-get update` seems work properly, see here the report [link](https://sites.google.com/site/mygithub/apt-get-update). after that, I run `sudo apt-get install indicator-datetime` again and obtain the same, see here the report [link](https://sites.google.com/site/mygithub/apt-get-install-indicator-datetime). In resume, it doesn't work.

Comment: @rayohauno: wait a day or two and try it again, or after a few hours.

Answer (score 0):

You have missing packages. Execute `sudo apt-get install libecal1.2-10 libedataserver1.2-15 libedataserverui-3.0-1` and then run `sudo apt-get install indicator-datetime` again. It should install successfully this time.

Comment: It doesn't solve the problem. After `sudo apt-get install libecal1.2-10 libedataserver1.2-15 libedataserverui-3.0-1` it says that:

`Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libecal1.2-10 is already the newest version.
libedataserver1.2-15 is already the newest version.
libedataserverui-3.0-1 is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.`

After `sudo apt-get install indicator-datetime` the message is the same as in the first post.